# How to create aligned table for the GitHub wiki?

Tags: github, open-source, wiki

I am auto-generating the description wiki pages for my class. The thing is when the [table is displayed](https://github.com/dvdvideo1234/Test/wiki), it automatically inserts some new lines, which brakes the function/method definition. For example `setFSensor` is:

```
E
:setFSensor(
V, V, N)
```

And it must be: `E:setFSensor( V, V, N)`
How can I make GitHub to display my custom table properly?

Comment: I don't see any extraneous newlines.

Comment: Yes, that's correct and yet it renders it like it has. I assume that the length of the column name must be longer. If so that may shorten the data, which is not the expected behavior. If I put spaces in the column name it just deletes them so i tough I'd go with placing `_` ( underscore )

Comment: So far extending `|---|` to `|----------|` has no effect also as expected to have.

Comment: No, what I mean is that I don't see anything strange in the way your wiki page is rendering (aside from some strange symbols that I think you're representing here with E, V, and N). I don't understand your question. An annotated screenshot might help.

Comment: These are not symbols, but in fact integrated images. The issue is that GitHub judges for the column width by counting the symbols in the column name, because if I put a long string as a column name it renders correctly. I cant seem to figure out what makes the top table different than the bottom table ? [HERE](https://github.com/dvdvideo1234/Test/blob/master/test_table.md)

Comment: The top table stretches the class factory and the bottom table renders the class methods correctly.

Comment: I was on mobile earlier and wasn't able to inspect the symbols to see if they were images or some Unicode symbol I wasn't familiar with. I don't think you can control the width of columns in a Markdown table on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

To overall control the width of the table column, I've put dots instead of underscores, dashes, and spaces. The name `Test API` extended becomes `...Test.API...` as a workaround.